# assigning values to a computed property vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, key, key-value

I have this array of objects:

```
columnData=[
  {Address: "1 fake st"},
  {Application: "bts sport"},
  {Description: "good"},
  {Issue Date: "2012-08-09"},
  {Status: "active"},
  {Unit: null}
]
```

And then I want to assign some of `columnData` elements to a new array of objects using a computed property and the new array should look like:

```
newData= [
  {
    label: "Address",
    value: "1 fake st"
  },
  {
    label: "Descripttion",
    value: "good"
  },
  {
    label: "Unit",
    value: null
  }
]
```

I have tried this piece of code but it doesn't work:

```
computed:{
    newData() {
      return [
        {
          label: Object.keys(this.columnData[0]),
          value: Object.values(this.columnData[0])
        },
        {
          label: Object.keys(this.columnData[2]),
          value: Object.values(this.columnData[2])
        },
        {
          label: Object.keys(this.columnData[5]),
          value: Object.values(this.columnData[5])
        }
      ];
    }
}
```

How can I create the `newData` array the way I want it to look like using a computed property?

Comment: What would be the expected output if one of the original objects contained multiple properties? Or no properties? Or is it guaranteed that each object contains only a single property? Also, how do you decide which objects from the input are included in the output?

Comment: my original object is guaranteed to be the way `columnData` is

Comment: `Object.keys(this.columnData[0])` returns one array, probably what you like to do is `Object.keys(this.columnData[0])[0]`; other values have same issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Object.keys(obj)[0]` and `Object.values(obj)[0]`, respectively to get the first property name and value of each object in the array.

```js
const columnData=[
  {Address: "1 fake st"},
  {Application: "bts sport"},
  {Description: "good"},
  {"Issue Date": "2012-08-09"},
  {Status: "active"},
  {Unit: null}
];
const newData = columnData.slice(0,2).concat(columnData[5]).map(obj=>({
  label: Object.keys(obj)[0],
  value: Object.values(obj)[0]
}));
console.log(newData);
```

You can also use `Object.entries` to get both the property name and value in one array.

```js
const columnData=[
  {Address: "1 fake st"},
  {Application: "bts sport"},
  {Description: "good"},
  {"Issue Date": "2012-08-09"},
  {Status: "active"},
  {Unit: null}
];
const newData = columnData.slice(0,2).concat(columnData[5]).map(obj=>{
  const [label, value] = Object.entries(obj)[0];
  return {label, value};
});
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Thank you but as I mentioned I want my array to include 'Address', 'Description' and 'Unit' not the entire values. Like this: 

```newData= [ {label: "Address", value: "1 fake st" }, {label: "Descripttion", value: "good"},  { label: "Unit", value: null }]```